# JSF, propagating event to every user

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Can I propagate event to every user which currently connected to application? For example as a popup? Even if the user isn't actively using the application but only has its windows opened? 
Actually requirement is to let to user know that a system is being shut down in X minutes.
Thank you.

**UPDATE**: as always before writing this post I hadn't any ideas, after writing this post ideas began to coming. I think about [`<p:poll>`  element](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/poll.xhtml) from Primefaces library. It should be invoked periodically and check some flag in a `session` or even `application` scoped bean. If this flag became **turned on** it should run popup window. Are there any pitfalls? Is there better idea?

Comment: Better idea is to use websockets with fallback to polling. PrimeFaces `p:socket` in recent versions support this.

Comment: @Kukeltje, thank you for idea, didn't know about this component, will give a try.